# Changing list of items attributes with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of items.

```
<img id="item0" src="">
<img id="item1" src="">
.
.
.
```

When someone clicks a button, I need change the srcs based on id.(every src with different link)

I want to use something like at the below.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $('#item' + i).attr('src', 'link')
}
```

Is something like this possible?
Actual code is this;

```
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

            var freeChampId=[];
            freeChampId.push(json['champions'][i].id);
            $.ajax({
                url:'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/tr/v1.2/champion/'+json['champions'][i].id+'?&api_key='+key,
                type:'GET',
                datatype:'json',
                data:{},
                success:function(json){

                    $("img[id^=freeChamp_Out]").each(function(){

                        $(this).attr('src','http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.2.1/img/champion/'+json['key']+'.png')

                    });
                }
            })


        }
```

Every loop turn the key and the link changes.

Comment: You can use a class for these images and then .each() https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to iterate over elements if you are setting same src to all of them. For this you can use attribute starts with selector to target all the images along with attr to set the required attribute
:

```
$("img[id^=item]").attr('src','link');
```

If the srcs are different:

```
$("img[id^=item]").each(function(){
  $(this).attr('src','link')
});
```

Comment: quoting the OP: _every src with different link_

Comment: I think this code will set same `link` to all the items here. Let's say we want to set `link1` to `item0`, `link2` to `item1` and soon. how can we do that? eventually setting _every src with different link_? current it just set the `link` to all the items.

Comment: @palaѕн: i am aware with that. op did not shared the connection that needs to be used to make the links dynamic for different different links

Comment: @Emre: how do you want the srcs to be??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar: Ok, I thought so. Hope OP will provide more details about it soon...

Comment: `for(var i=0;i<10;i++){

            var freeChampId=[];
            freeChampId.push(json['champions'][i].id);
            $.ajax({
                url:'https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/tr/v1.2/champion/'+json['champions'][i].id+'?&api_key='+key,
                type:'GET',
                datatype:'json',
                data:{},
                success:function(json){

                    $("img[id^=freeChamp_Out]").each(function(){

$(this).attr('src','http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/5.2.1/img/champion/'+json['key']+'.png')});}})}`